# XML parsing is returning null for attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <DT100>
   <company_id>online00020120523888</company_id>
   <template_type>100</template_type>
   <import_seq>1</import_seq>
   <field_name>cust_acct_no</field_name>
   <display_name>Account No</display_name>
   <data_type>0</data_type>
   <internal_num>0</internal_num>
   <internal_info>{}</internal_info>
  </DT100>
   .
   .
   .
```

for each DT100, I'm trying to read the import_seq and field_name into a dictionary. But, when I step through the debugger, I'm getting null for import_seq and field_name. Here's my code, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm using some earlier code I wrote to parse XML, so I think it *should* be working, but its not.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("foo.xtp");
String feed = doc.ToString();

string import_seq = "";
string field_name = "";
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(feed));

Dictionary<string, string> custXML = new Dictionary<string, string>();
r.ReadToFollowing("NewDataSet");

if(r.ReadToDescendant("DT100"))
{
   do
    {
      import_seq = r.GetAttribute("import_seq");
      field_name = r.GetAttribute("field_name");
      custXML.Add(import_seq, field_name);

     }
    while (r.ReadToNextSibling("DT100"));
}
```

Many thanks,

Amanda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dictionary with this simple Linq to Xml query:

```
Dictionary<int, string> custXML = 
            doc.Descendants("DT100")
               .ToDictionary(d => (int)d.Element("import_seq"),
                             d => (string)d.Element("field_name"));
```

And yes, as you can see, values you want to extract are elements, not attributes. Read about difference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp).

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm, and yeah, I'm still learning my XML terminology!

Comment: @Amanda_Panda I think this link will be very useful for you http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the values of `import_seq` and `field_name` aren't *attributes*, they're *elements* (children of the `<DT100>` element). You can keep reading the elements from the reader (not too easy), or you can use something like LINQ-to-XML or serialization to retrieve the data.